# UIActivityViewController in a PopOverViewController Crashing in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a UIActivityViewController for a share button. For iPhone I have it as a regular UIActivityViewController and for iPad its in a PopOverViewController. This is the code I have for it

```
let textToShare = "Check out this website!"

if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com/") {
   let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
   let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

   if let popUpVC = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
      popUpVC.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
      popUpVC.sourceRect = share.frame
   }
   self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When I press the share button on a iPad it just crashes with a (lldb). But when I have it present from a view it works but isn't in the right position. This is the code I am using for the present  from a view.

```
popUpVC.sourceView = self.view
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you have to check if the device you are currently running on responds to popoverPresentationController because `popoverPresentationController` is new to iOS 8 and will crash on iOS 7. It'll also be nil on iPhone because it's only in a `UIPopover` on iPad.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myText, myUrl], applicationActivities: nil)

if activityViewController.respondsToSelector("popoverPresentationController") {
   // iOS8+
   view.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
} else {
   view.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: how would i use a sourceRect instead of a view because I am using this and it crashes                                 activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = share.frame